# Dynamically load image on click in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an on click event that will load a specific image based on the button being clicked. Currently my html is:

```
  <nav>
    <a class="link" href="#">1</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">2</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">3</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">4</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">5</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">6</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">7</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">8</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">9</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">10</a>
    <a class="link" href="#">11</a>
  </nav>
  <div id="image"></div>
```

Based on the link, I want each of these to load the associated image:

```
var item = document.querySelectorAll(".link");
var itemID = [];

for (var x = 0; x < item.length; x++) {
    itemID[x] = x + 1;
  }
for (var i = 0; i < (item.length); i++) {
  img = itemID[i];
  item[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector("#image").innerHTML = '<img src="' + img + '.png">';
  });
}
```

The code is loading the image properly, but it only ever loads "11.png" for every link. Link 1 should load 1.png, Link 2 should load 2.png, etc.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but I feel I'm misunderstanding how to use addEventListener correctly? Any help would very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here: `img = itemID[I];` 
`img` is not declared and is global, so on every iteration it change value and so the old tag img change src accordingly.

Try to declare a new img on every iteration:

```
let img = itemID[i];
```